# Trying to use a HTML file as my email body using iMsg in VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, html-email

I've wrote a script to create a HTML file based on a SQL Query....  It has become necessary to have that HTML be emailed.  Most of our execs use blackberry's and I want to send the HTML file as the body.  I have found a round about way to get this done, by adding a WebBrowser, and having the web browser then load the file,  and then using the below code to send.  The problem i'm facing is if I automate the code fully, it will only email part of the HTML document, now if I add a button, and make it do the email function, it sends correctly.  I have added a wait function in several different location, thinking it may be an issue with the HTML not being fully created before emailing.  I have to get this 100% automated.  Is there a way I can use the .HTMLBody to link to the actual HTML file stored on the C:(actual path is C:\Turnover.html).  Thanks all for any help.

Public Sub Email()
        Dim strdate
        Dim iCfg As Object
        Dim iMsg As Object

```
    strdate = Date.Today.TimeOfDay

    iCfg = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    With iCfg.Fields
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "xxxxx.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendemailaddress") = """Turnover Report"" <TurnoverReports@xxxxx.com>"
        .Update()
    End With

    With iMsg
        .Configuration = iCfg
        .Subject = "Turnover Report"
        .To = "xxxxx@xxxxx.com"
        '.Cc = ""

        .HTMLBody = WebBrowserReportView.DocumentText


        .Send()
    End With



    iMsg = Nothing
    iCfg = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: If you already *have* the HTML, there is no need to load it into a WebBrowser control before sending. Just send that HTML text as message body.

Comment: but its different each time i want it to email, it's basically showing tasks from a shift perspective i.e. 1st, 2nd and 3rd, so the html file is different each time, that's why I want it to send the file.

Comment: just read in that HTML file into a string (no need to display) and use that string to fill that `.HTMLBody`. Or did I misunderstand and does that HTML file create the report through javascript when it's displayed? (I understood that the reporting software created that HTML)

Comment: I should have stated i'm very new at this.  LOL.  That sounds like it works, let me see if I can figure out how to do that.  Feel free to give me the answer if you know how.  I'll start looking for myself also.

Answer (score 1):

used the below function to read in a local html file. then set

`TextBox2.Text = getHTML("C:\Turnover2.html")`

and also

`.HTMLBody = TextBox2.Text`

```
Private Function getHTML(ByVal address As String) As String
    Dim rt As String = ""

    Dim wRequest As WebRequest
    Dim wResponse As WebResponse

    Dim SR As StreamReader

    wrequest = WebRequest.Create(address)
    wResponse = wrequest.GetResponse
    SR = New StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream)

    rt = SR.ReadToEnd
    SR.Close()

    Return rt

End Function
```